# java jbutton image png clickable area

Tags: java, swing, png, jbutton, absolutelayout

I want to do a `JButton` with PNG icon but the clickable area have to be a pixel and not a transparency pixel, and position this `JButton` over other `JButton`s like position absolute in css.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Create a JLabel with the imge and add a MouseListener. In the listener check Point of the MouseEvent. Get pixel from the image for the point and check alpha of the image's point color. If it's not transparent do your action.